# DTF: Update a File within an Archive Without Extracting It

Tags: wix, wix3.5, custom-action, dtf

I am using the [Deployment Tools Foundation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2008/05/16/a-brief-history-of-the-deployment-tools-foundation-project.aspx) bundled with WiX 3.5. There is an archive that contains a file that I want to update without having to extract it first - the edits are based on user inputs during setup.

How do I obtain a reference to this file, perform the updates, and save the changes to the file without needing to extract it from the archive? The custom action is being written in C#.

I am using [Wix v3.5.2415](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/3.5.2415.0/), which is the same version for the DTF assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using one of the free c# libraries to interact with a zip file.

For example:
[SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpziplib.com/)
[SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/)

I'm not sure exactly why you are trying to avoid unzipping.  Is this a silverlight xap file by chance?  If so, I recommend a different approach like using [initParams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189004%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: I ended up unzipping the file in question, performing my edits, then updating the zip with the new version of the file. Thanks!